# The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 48. The Windows SChannel error state is 552

Tags: ssl, application-pool

After installing IBM System i Accesss for windows V6R1M0 i have application pooling which can't start

and i get the above errors:

1. A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 48. The Windows SChannel error state is 552.
2. The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.